# Checking a value within a function Unit Testing

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, assertions

I'm trying to find out how I would go about creating a Unit Test to check the value of a variable that is within a function? I have the below code which only works if the variable is global which I get, but that's not what I want to do. I just want to test the value of the variable when its within the main function. How can I go about doing this? Here's my code:

Run Code

```
def main():
    #Declare Variable Here
    Gold = 4000

def treasure_chest(amount):
    print("I have ",amount," Gold!")
```

Here's my test suite

```
from Functions import main
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_valueContains(self):
        value =  Gold
        self.assertEquals(4000, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: This is a bit of an anti-pattern. The test should treat the code as a black box. eg "If given appropriate input does it provide correct output"? One reason for this is that how the code is implemented could change. As long as it does the same job as before, the unit test shouldn't care _how_ it does it. A contrived example would be splitting the treasure into gold and gems which may have different value. The `treasure_chest` function could calculate the value correctly but your unit test might still fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't access any variables that are local to the function. In fact, they don't really exist outside of that scope. Even if you could do this, it is probably not what you want to do. It is much better to treat functions as, well, functions, and verify that for a given input that produce the proper output and/or side effects.

But! You still can check the value of `Gold`, although not with unittest. You can use Python's built in `assert` keyword. This is not the same as the `TestCase.assertSomething` functions that come with the unittest module, this can be used anywhere in your code. For instance,

```
def main():

  #Declare Variable Here
  Gold = 4000
  assert Gold == 4000

def treasure_chest(amount):

    assert Gold <= somethingElse
    print("I have ",amount," Gold!")
```

Using the `assert` keyword effectively is actually **really** good programming style. It is not a replacement for unit testing, nor does it do exactly the same thing, rather it works along side of unit tests to verify invariants in your code. Which means catching bugs faster!

The syntax of the assert statement is outlined here, https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html. Put in the most simple form, you give it a boolean expression and it will check that the value is `True`. If it is not, it will raise an `AssertionError`.

Usually you only want to use `assert` to assert values that MUST be correct. A common idiom is to use it to `assert` parameters on private methods/functions, since we are to assume that the input to these methods has already be sanitised and should be valid.

For instance,

```
class Foo():

    __init__(self, val):
       if val < 0:
           raise InvalidValueOrSomething

       __val = val

   __modify_val(self):
       assert self.__val < 0
       # Do some stuff...
```

Note that assertions are **always run** by default, even when not testing.

Assertions can be disabled at run-time with the `-O` flag to the interpreter, although it is not recommended (https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively)

Comment: Awesome! and great detail. Thanks. I kinda assumed I wouldn't be able to do it. Just wanted to make absolutely sure. But your example with the built in `assert` method is awesome. Thank you

Comment: @Salce__ Glad to help! Just an FYI `assert` is a keyword to create a special assert statement in language, not really a method (which is a function attached to an object.) =)

Comment: @Salce__ Also I would check out Aaron's answer below. Returning a closure is very neat. It is probably not what I would do to test a variable in general, but understanding how closures work can be very helpful and fun!

Answer (score 2):

You can't and shouldn't do it the way you're doing it, but you can do it with a closure returning the function that you can call later:

```
def closure(Gold):
    Gold = Gold
    def treasure_chest():
        print("I have", Gold,"Gold!")

    return treasure_chest
```

test suite

```
from Functions import closure
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.amount = 4000
        self.treasure_chest = closure(self.amount)

    def test_valueContains(self):
        self.assertEquals(self.amount, self.treasure_chest.__closure__[0].cell_contents)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```